# linkbutton in a repeater c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a database where i am displaying books. Main page displays 2 links category( fiction, technical)
You click on technical then it takes you to a new page where it queries the technical books

From there i am using a repeater to display those technical books.. including the picture.

My question is i want to be able to make the name a link and when the user clicks that link some variable knows the name and i am taken to a new page where then i could use that variable to query the database to display the right information again. Im not sure if a variable is the way to go.

Or, if query string could work - something like:

```
Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["BookName"]);
```

So, i guess there are 2 questions..

1. How do i make name a link and navigate to the new page "Book.aspx"
2. how can i save that name that is clicked so the book page would know it(name) so i could use that name in a query ?

Here is what i have..

```
<h2>Books in category</h2>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>

        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
       <div>
         <img src='/images/<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Image") %>'  onclick="Navigate()"
          alt="" align="left" style="height:100px;width:100px;border:1px solid black"   />
      </div>
      <table  class="vertaligntop">
      <tr >
      <td >
 <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "BookName") %>
 <br />
 <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "BookDescription") %>
 <br />
 <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ISBN") %>
 <br />
  <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Author") %>
 <br />
 <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CategoryName") %>
 <br />
  <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Publisher") %>
 <br />
  <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Rating") %>
 <br />
 <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Price") %>
 <br />
 </td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In aspx page change data bind for `BookName` as:

```
<a href='Book.aspx?BookName=<%# Eval("BookName")%>'><%# Eval("BookName")%></a>
```

And in your code behind of the next page, save `BookName` into `ViewState` and use it when it is required:

```
public string BookName
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["BookName"] == null)
            ViewState["BookName"] = Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["BookName"]);
        return Convert.ToString(ViewState["BookName"]);
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["BookName"] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: in the next page how would i get that name in the code behind?

Comment: Next page means `Book.aspx` page? If so, please write the above property to your code behind of your next page and use the property when it is needed as: `string selectedBookName= BookName;`

Comment: I did what you said and assigned the BookName toa label so i could see what the value is but what i get is not the name but rather <% that instead. Why? I used your code BTW

Comment: Sorry, there was a problem while using `hyperlink` server control, it can't bind data, I'm going to change my answer accordingly and going to use `a`, please see my answer again, thanks for your time.